# How to deterministically interleave N heterogeneous lists of different lengths?

Tags: python, list, pseudocode

Here's my goal: I have **N lists** (let's say N=3) of different sizes, each one containing a different type of items and I'd need to **generate a single list** containing all of them, **minimizing the number of adjacent items of the same type**.

I'm personally using python, but any pseudocode solution would be accepted.

Example:

```
A = [a1, a2, a3]
B = [b1, b2]
C = [c1, c2, c3, c4]

OUT = f(A, B, C)
> [a1, b1, c1, a2, b2, c2, a3, c3, c4]
```

In the example above I'd be simply iterating the 3 lists at the same time and picking one item from each, until every item is taken. It's pretty simple, fast and deterministic.
(Note: the number of adjacent similar items is not optimally minimized, but let's say it's tolerable in most use cases)

**BUT**

I'd prefer to avoid the *a,b,c,a,b,c,...* pattern and make it look more "natural", although still **deterministic** (read: same input, same output).

Example:

```
OUT = [a1, b1, c1, b2, a2, c2, a3, c3, c4]
```

Any suggestion?

P.s. for a real-world example, let's image these 3 lists contain 3 different types of articles (news, tutorials and reviews) and we're generating the list of suggested/recommented articles for our blog.

Comment: You could choose the next element to be appended to the resulting list using a pseudorandom algorithm that always uses the same seed.

Comment: The only way that you are forced to have adjacent elements from the same category is if that category has at least 2 more elements than all others put together. So, it's easy to minimize adjacencies inductively by combining the lists from smallest to largest. However, I suspect that you have other criteria you haven't stated.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my proposal:

```
import random

def mix(ls):
    random.seed(0)

    final_length = sum([len(l) for l in ls])
    r = []
    while len(r) < final_length:
        l = ls[random.randint(0, len(ls) - 1)]
        if len(l) > 0:
            r.append(l.pop())    
    return r
```

Then, you can use it with:

```
a = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3']
b = ['b1', 'b2']
c = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4']

r = mix([a, b, c])
```

And the result will be:

```
['c4', 'c3', 'b2', 'a3', 'b1', 'c2', 'a2', 'c1', 'a1']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

def interleave(*lists):
    random.seed("OWA TAGOO SIAM") #ensures deterministic behaviour
    lists = list(lists) # so its mutable 
    for i in range(max(map(len,lists))): 
        random.shuffle(lists) #randomize the order of the lists
        for j in lists:
            if i < len(j):
                yield j[i]

A = [a1, a2, a3]
B = [b1, b2]
C = [c1, c2, c3, c4]    

print list(interleave(A,B,C))
```

Comment: This will not be deterministic, unless you set the seed first. Also, `shuffle` is a function from the `random` module, not a method of lists.

Comment: ahh good point ... (I dont use shuffle much and added it as an afterthought)